# Validation is not used while my conditions are met.

Tags: javascript, validation, function

Here is my code:

```
function getTable(strExp){
this.strExp = strExp;
console.log(strExp);
var strTBL = "";
if (strExp === "Res"){
    for (var it = 0; it > 3; it++){
    strTBL = strTBL + jsonData.Table.ResTBL[it];
    console.log("Im in");
    }
}
else if (valeur === "Dice"){
}
return strTBL;
}
```

In my script I do this call : document.getElementById("ResTBL").innerHTML = getTable("Res")

When I see my console log I don't see the I'm in log, but it gives me the value of strExp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place `it < 3` in a cycle

```
for (var it = 0; it < 3; it++) {
    strTBL = strTBL + jsonData.Table.ResTBL[it];
    console.log("Im in");
}
```

Comment: I feel so bad... dislexia is crap when coding!